# How to deal with tooltips for rotated rectangles using d3-tip or other library?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a couple of rectangles on SVG, all of them have rotations. Here is the code:

```
d3.select(#Scene).('svg').selectAll("rect")
.data(rectData)
.attr("x", d => d.x)
.attr("y", d => d.y)
.attr("width", d => d.width)
.attr("height", d => d.height)
.attr("transform", d => 'rotate(' + d.rotation + ' ' + (d.x *2 + d.width)/2 +' ' + (d.y *2 + d.height)/2 +')');
```

I tried to use d3-tip.js library to show tip:

```
const tip = d3Tip.default()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .html(d => {
            return d.name;
        });

svg.call(tip);

svg.selectAll(".tooltip")
   .on('mouseover', tip.show)
   .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

It looks like this now:

[image]

But I need to look over top middle point. Any ideas?

Comment: Could u please provide a fiddle?

Comment: d3-tip has an offset attribute, e.g. `.offset([-8, 0])` You could maybe try adjusting the offset, otherwise, on `mouseover` dynamically change the positioning of the tooltip like this `tooltip.style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px").style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")`